After using taskkill, Node.js server isn't working anymore
I'm facing an issue with my Node.js server after using the taskkill command to terminate a process running on port 3000. Here's the problem and what I've tried so far:
Problem:
I was developing a Node.js application running on port 3000. After using the following command to terminate a process:
taskkill /PID <Process ID> /F

I started experiencing issues where my server. It starts but gives this error when I open the site in the browser:
User 'index.htm' not found
What I've tried:

Ran netstat -ano | findstr :3000 but no processes are currently using the port.
Restarted the computer:

Rebooted to ensure no lingering processes are holding onto the port. The problem persists after restarting.

Updated my server code to use a different port (e.g., 8000)

Completely uninstalled and reinstalled Node.js. Verified installation with node -v.

Verified that no Windows system processes (e.g., IIS or System PID 4) are occupying the port.



I don't see how these two events could be linked, especially there was a reboot. taskkill kills a task and that's it. "User 'index.htm' not found" - it's unclear what kind of error is it, I'd suggest to focus on this. Is it observed regardless whether node server runs or not? It's not shown what requests you make and to which host. If you use localhost try to use ip and check hosts file. Also try another browser and make sure you're not using a proxy

Make sure that the file index.htm exists in the correct directory where Node.js is trying to access it. Verify the path to ensure there are no typos or mismatches. If you are using a relative path, confirm that the index.htm file is in the expected directory.
Check also the file extension, file permissions, and the server logs for more details !
It's a good start !

And perhaps reinstall dependancies sometimes they can be corrupted !

I’ve already tried all of these things
I even ran a demo file with a simple server setup to rule out issues with my current code. The demo code I used is something that worked perfectly fine before, and there’s no reason for it to fail now. unless something broke after the taskkill command I ran earlier.

Have you try to reinstall and/or migrate all in a new server ?

I’ve already tried reinstalling Node.js and all dependencies. I’ve also migrated the project to a new folder on the same machine, but the issue persists.
If by a new server you mean a completely different environment (e.g., a new machine or VM), I haven’t tried that yet. The thing is that it won't let me run ANY code

Yes, i have thinking about a new machine or VM. I think that in a first time, if you change your environnement it is a good idea for test if the problem doesn't come about your folder.
